# Scala underscore asterisk in Variadic Function?

Tags: scala

I'm currently following [Functional Programming In Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala)

This is the psuedo-implementation of `apply` in `List[A]`

```
def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] = 
  if (as.isEmpty) Nil
  else ::(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
```

If I omit `: _*` in `as.tail: _*`, scala complains for type mismatch, which makes sense since `as.tail` is `Seq[A]` here.

But what does `_*` exactly do here?

Edit::

Correct terminology for such is **sequence wildcard**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `: _*` notation just tells the scala compiler to treat the elements of the collection that you passed into the method (the collection which proceeds `: _*` in the arguments) as if they had been passed one by one into the varargs method. For example, if you have

```
def foo(x: Int*) = x.sum
val xs = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

then

```
foo(xs: _*)
```

works as if you had typed

```
foo(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Interesting. So am I correct to think that `_*` is a **special construct** rather than another complex underscore rule, which I failed to understand? I've yet to encounter another example where underscore is used to annotate type (except for _existential type_). Thanks

Comment: "sequence argument" http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#function-applications

Comment: Corresponds to "sequence wildcard" in "pattern sequence", http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-sequences

Comment: Another _hidden_ feature in Scala. Thank you!